# How convert curl request into scala simply

Tags: scala, curl

I new to scala.
I want to convert my curl request into scala but I find many way to handle it. I want the simply way possible. This a example of my request:

```
curl \
--request POST \
--data '{"jwt": "myjwtkey, "role": "myrole"}' \
"http://myvault.com:8200/v1/auth/login"
```

I try this

```
  def getTokenFromVault(signedJWT: String, vaultAddr: String, vaultAuthPath: String, vaultRole: String): String = {
    case class TokenRequest(jwt: String, role: String)
    try {
      val requestData = TokenRequest(signedJWT, vaultRole)
      val request = basicRequest
        .post(uri"$vaultAddr/v1/$vaultAuthPath")
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .contentType("application/json")
        .body(requestData)
 
      val response = request.send()
      response.body
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        throw new Exception(s"Failed to retrieve token from Vault: ${e.getMessage}")
    }
```

but have many problems to build it.

Comment: which rest api client you are using?

Comment: i'm using com.softwaremill.sttp.client3

Comment: what build problem you are seeing?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of sending a request using sttp client3.
you need to convert/serialize the case class to JSON

```
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.write
import sttp.client3._


def getTokenFromVault(signedJWT: String, vaultAddr: String, vaultAuthPath: String, vaultRole: String): Either[String, String] = {
    implicit val sttpBackend = HttpURLConnectionBackend()
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    case class TokenRequest(jwt: String, role: String)
    try {
      val requestData = TokenRequest(signedJWT, vaultRole)
      val requestDataJSON = write(requestData)


      val request = basicRequest
        .post(uri"$vaultAddr/v1/$vaultAuthPath")
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .contentType("application/json")
        .body(requestDataJSON)

      val response = request.send(sttpBackend)
      response.body
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        throw new Exception(s"Failed to retrieve token from Vault: ${e.getMessage}")
    }
  }
```

Add the following dependencies to build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.softwaremill.sttp.client3" %% "core" % "3.9.2",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "4.0.6",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "4.0.6"
)
```